# How do I impersonate a windows domain account user from a linux process?

Tags: authentication, active-directory

I'm running a process on a Unix box (I think it's a recent version of Red Hat, I can check for more detailed info if relevant), under a local user.

I would like to access some network resources, via a Windows domain account.

How do I/Can I associate the local user with a windows domain account just for the purposes of running this one process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accessing files

There are various ways to do this, but the simplest is probably to use Nautilus.

#### Installation

To access Samba Shares through Nautilus install the `gvfs-smb` package, available in the official Yum repositories.

```
$ yum search gvfs-smb
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
=============================================================== N/S matched: gvfs-smb ================================================================
gvfs-smb.x86_64 : Windows fileshare support for gvfs
```

If it's not installed:

```
$ sudo yum install gvfs-smb
```

Then from Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and enter `smb://servername/share` in the location bar to access your share. The mounted share is likely to be present at `/run/user/<your_UID>/gvfs` in the filesystem.

#### Example

After putting the following into Nautilus' location bar, `smb://sam@bart/mp3s-1`.

[image: ss of windows' domain credentials]

After providing the appropriate credentials you'll see the windows share, from the window's CIFS server.

[image: ss of CIFS share]

**NOTE:** In the above example, `bart` is the windows server, the user is `sam`, and the CIFS share is `/mp3s-1`.

### Accessing processes

To interact with processes on a Windows system from a Linux system you can use the tool [`winexe`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/). It should be in most distros' repos.

#### Examples

*See the list of processes / logged in users*

```
$ winexe --system -U 'DOMAIN\Administrator%password' //192.168.10.21 "tasklist /V"
```

*Start cmd.exe console*

```
$ winexe --system -U 'DOMAIN\Administrator%password' //192.168.10.21 cmd.exe
```

*screenshot*

[image: ss of winexe in action]

#### References

- [Accessing Windows console remotely from Linux](http://blog.wpkg.org/2008/06/15/accessing-windows-console-remotely-from-linux/)

Comment: is nautilus only useful for accessing samba shares? can i use it, to, for example, authenticate against a running process somewhere (say, sqlserver or a printer queue)?

Comment: @blueberryfields - I thought that might be what you really wanted but I wanted to see if you were thinking of file access only, first. See my updates, I show how to use `winexe` to access window's systems remotely via cli.